# Grub Rescue: Format Entire Harddrive

Tags: boot, command-line, grub2, hard-drive, grubrescue

I am really getting frustrated trying to solve the grub rescue prompt. I understand that I deleted the partition that Ubuntu was on, and therefore, I deleted the config files for grub--causing the current mess. But I do not have a backup Windows CD--Dell never sent me one, so the procedure of using Windows Repair is unlikely for me.

At this point, I would like to just format the entire harddrive, all partitions, go back to a clean slate.

Aftewards, I will reinstall Ubuntu without having to worry about the complications of a "dual boot" until I can at least start up an OS when I turn on my PC. How can I do this?

EDIT: I tried booting up with a USB and run DBAN--but it failed.

Comment: grub consists of a number of parts; part 1 is the MBR (first 512 bytes sector of the disk, which is the rescue mode plus pointer to later parts).  part 1.5 is the main program of grub which MBR points to before part 2 puts up the menu.  If you formatted the partition that grub was on, the whole grub program is gone (only the limited grub menu that fits on MBR will remain).  However "How can I do this?" referring to what?  If you formatted ubuntu - grub is gone, and the fix is windows media `fixboot /mbr` (command varies on ver of windoze installed `bootrec /fixmbr`) if windoze is still there

Comment: you can also set the default boot options from bios

Comment: if you recently install dual boot os, you can set default boot manager from bios.

Comment: is this an EFI system? if it is, simply delete /EFI/ubuntu/ from the EFI partition.